# mysql password is messing up my dump

Tags: bash, mysql

ok so i need to do a mysqldump of a database and this is what i have

```
mysqldump -uroot -psdfas@N$pr!nT --databases app_pro > /srv/DUMPFILE.SQL
```

but i am getting this error

```
 -bash: !nT: event not found
```

seems to be having a hard time with the password...any other way to mysql dump

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Put `-psdfas@N$pr!nT` in single quotes:

```
mysqldump -uroot '-psdfas@N$pr!nT' --databases app_pro > /srv/DUMPFILE.SQL
```

The problem is that bash is interpreting the `!`. Strings in single quotes aren't interpreted.

Comment: I am trying just to access the database and I cannot get the password to work. My password ends in an exclamation mark so I've tried placing the entire -p command within single quotes but I still get "Error 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Answer (score 11):

You need to escape the '!' in the password:-

```
-psdfas@N$pr\!nT
```

Comment: That's not enough; the `$pr` bit will be interpreted as a variable substitution, so you either need to also escape the `$`, or single-quote the whole password, or (best) type it in on a separate prompt.

Answer (score 2):

The answers so far dodge the point that you shouldn't put the password in the command line.  See [MySQL's End-User Guidelines for Password Security](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/password-security-user.html) for how to do this without revealing your password.

Comment: Of course this isn't a problem if it's a one-time command... but then I'd think you'd just -p and type the password at the prompt in that case.

Comment: One-time commands still get recorded in shell history, and are visible to anyone who happens to run `ps`.  Putting a password on a command line is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

Like others already said you should never specify a password on the command line since any other process on the machine is able to read it. A simple and effective solution for mysql is to use a `.my.cnf` file in the home directory of the user running mysql or mysqldump.

First create it in a secure way:

```
sudo touch /root/.my.cnf
sudo chown 0:0 /root/.my.cnf
sudo chmod 600 /root/.my.cnf
```

then make sure `/root/.my.cnf` contains something like this:

```
[mysql]
user=root
password=sdfas@N$pr!nT

[mysqldump]
user=root
password=sdfas@N$pr!nT
```

You can and should do this for your “normal” (non-root) mysql account as well. Then you never have to type your password again and still be secure. Just put a .my.cnf in your own home directory with your credentials in it and make sure only you are able to read and write to the file:

```
touch ~/.my.cnf
chmod 600 /root/.my.cnf
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
mysqldump -u root --password='sdfas@N$pr!nT' app_pro > /srv/DUMPFILE.SQL
```

Comment: That won't work. the $ will be interepreted within the double-quoted string and the shell will look for a `$pr` variable, which won't exist and evaluate to a null string, changing the password to `sdfas@N!nT`. Using single quotes would be fine, however.

Comment: Makes sense.  PHP does the same sort of thing

Answer (score 0):

According to the <strike>destructions</strike> instructions, the arguments should have double hyphens. (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)

Try this:

```
mysqldump --user=root --password=psdfas@N$pr!nT --databases app_pro > /srv/DUMPFILE.SQL
```

Comment: I don't know why it isn't documented there, but the man page does list `-ppassword`, etc.

Comment: Interesting. Judging from the other answers, the problem is not in the argument delimiter but rather the exclamation mark in the password.

Answer (score 0):

when you use ! in a command line, it means, find the last run command that starts with the following letters and place it here..
go to your command line and run "history" and then run some other comands, cd, ls, whatever.
then go !h   the last command you ran that started with the letter 'h' (in this case "history") will be executed.

you'll need to escape out that bang (!)

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off history expansion:

```
set +o histexpand
```