# mysql cannot connect to database if password is specified inline

Tags: mysql

I have a problem that I think it is something easy.

I want to connect to mysql database.

If I do the following:

```
mysql -uroot -premoved mydatabase
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

But if I do:

```
mysql -uroot -p mydatabase
Enter password: removed
mysql>
```

It works!!
Why?

Comment: Does your actual password have any unusual characters in it? These might be interpolated by the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need single quotes around your password.

`mysql -uroot '-pabc$def' mydatabase`

See [mysql password is messing up my dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610028/mysql-password-is-messing-up-my-dump) for reference.